# pandas apply lambda on column values and select those whose set size is > 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select the rows in a `df`, that within each row, the set size of a column value is > 1;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, 3],
               'a': [41, 4, 5],
               'b': [3, 13, 6]})

df['concat'] = (df['a'].astype(str) + df['b'].astype(str))

df.groupby('concat')['col'].apply(set).to_dict()
```

but this only applies `set` to each column ('col') value.

python prevent me from

```
df.groupby('concat')['col'].apply(lambda x: set(x) if len(set(x)) > 1).to_dict()
```

Comment: Wait, can you please explain what your expected output is in the first place?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `{'413': {0, 1}}`

Comment: Okay... you mean `{'413: [1, 2]}` well, if I can guarantee you the items are unique, does it matter if it's a set or not?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i guess not

Comment: with so many solutions, dont know which one is faster

Comment: I would be leaning towards a non-apply solution but I have been surprised in the past. The best is to just time them all and select the best one. Or else throw a dice and choose one answer ;-)

Comment: @daiyue - The best test it with your real data.

Comment: @daiyue I'm curious to know what the test timings were on your data. Indulge me (please?)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) because `set` is iterable:

```
s = df.groupby('concat')['col'].apply(set)

d = s[s.str.len() > 1].to_dict()
print (d)
{'413': {1, 2}}
```

Comment: why `str.len` can be applied to `set` values? i though it only applies to strings

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (that does not require `apply`) uses `groupby.unique` -

```
v = df.groupby('concat').col.unique()
v[v.str.len() > 1]

concat
413    [1, 2]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

You can call `to_dict` on this result -

```
v[v.str.len() > 1].to_dict()
{'413': array([1, 2])}
```

Or, if your end goal is internet data exchange, then directly serialise to JSON -

```
v[v.str.len() > 1].to_json()
'{"413":[1,2]}'
```

Note that arrays and sets are implicitly serialised to JSON list objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.map` for this:

```
res = df.groupby('concat')['col'].apply(set)
res_dict = res[res.map(len)>1].to_dict()
```